# Sort after Map/Reduce with inline result

Tags: mongodb, mapreduce

After trying this [solution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9643876/map-reduce-and-sort-nested-document) and getting one step further i have another question regarding mongodb.

My question is:

How can i sort the output of:

```
doc = {_id : 16, days : { 1 : 123, 2 : 129, 3 : 140, 4 : 56, 5 : 57, 6 : 69, 7 : 80 }};
db.so.insert(doc);

map = function() {
  emit(this._id, this.days["1"]);
  emit(this._id, this.days["3"]); 
  emit(this._id, this.days["7"]); 
}

reduce = function (k, vals) {
  var sum = 0;
  vals.forEach(function (v) {sum += v;});
  return sum;
}

res = db.so.mapReduce(map, reduce, {out : {inline : 1}});
res.find();
```

The Output is like this:

```
"results" : [
    {
            "_id" : 16,
            "value" : 225
    },
    {
            "_id" : 33,
            "value" : 230
    },
    {
            "_id" : 302,
            "value" : 274
    }
```

]

Now i want to sort the result with:

```
res.find().sort({ "results.value":-1 });
```

which results in this error:

```
Sat Mar 31 01:15:45 TypeError: res.find().sort({'results.value':-1}) is not a function (shell):1
```

Does anybody can help me ?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Here's an example of the same query using the MongoDB 2.2 [Aggregation Framework](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/applications/aggregation/):

```
db.so.aggregate(
  { $project : {
     '_id' : 1,
     'value' : { $add : ["$days.1","$days.3","$days.7"] },
  }},
  { $sort: { 'value': -1 }}
)
```

.. and the output:

```
{
    "result" : [
        {
            "_id" : 302,
            "value" : 274
        },
        {
            "_id" : 33,
            "value" : 230
        },
        {
            "_id" : 16,
            "value" : 225
        }
    ],
    "ok" : 1
}
```

Answer (score 6):

This will not work in that way with `inline` results. Instead, try writing to a collection and then running a sort on that collection.

```
res = db.so.mapReduce(map, reduce, {out : "tmpResults"});
db.tmpResult.find().sort({value:-1});
```

Comment: do you think this would be possible with the new mongo aggregation framework ?

Comment: Yes, I believe you can do this with the aggregation framework. Looks like you `$project` the `_id` and the `sum` and then use the `$sort`. This should be pretty easy to test as 2.1 is available for download.

Answer (score 5):

You can totally sort the `results` attribute:

```
res = db.so.mapReduce(map, reduce, {out : {inline : 1}});
res.results.sort(function (a, b) {
    if (a.value == b.value) {
        return 0;
    }
    return a.value < b.value ? -1 : 1;
});
```